# CountDown Timer is not Stopping Value ListView in Android

Tags: android

I have problem in `CountDownTimer` its not Stoping the values properly.
Problem is:

In ListView -Every Swipe in listrow countdownTimer will start and stop -its functionality
For Example:
If I started Simultaneously 4 row for Swipe start countdowntimer is started. Already described different minutes for each row.
If i stopped one row for swipe again to stop -
using `countdownTimer.cancel()` and
 `countdownTimer.onFinish();` Its not stopping the value  and  i tried to  removing the list for `Arraylist` in  listview and `adapter` also  `dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` its carring the  previous timer   its showing the below row of `listview`. Please Any one give me solution ..i m tried to solve this problem

Comment: Update the question to the code inserted one.